# Friending a typedef-ed class (c++)

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, friend

I am going through a bit of a crisis where I need to friend a template class that is typedefed, but I am getting loads of errors(too many to paste here). I have put the MRE [here](https://github.com/mes-elf/Friend_typedef_class) so you guys don't have to set up the files.

Here are the .h files for completeness-sake:

```
//Keyboard.h
#pragma once
namespace wm
{
    namespace io
    {
        class Keyboard
        {
            //friend wm::MessageHandler;
        private:
            Keyboard(const Keyboard&) = delete;
            void operator=(const Keyboard&) = delete; 
            Keyboard() = default;

        public:
            static Keyboard& Instance();
            static void SomeServerFunc();

        public:
            static void SomeClientFunc();
        };
    }
}

//Mouse.h
#pragma once
namespace wm
{
    namespace io
    {
        class Mouse
        {
            //friend wm::MessageHandler;
            //friend class wm::MessageHandler; ??
        private:
            Mouse(const Mouse&) = delete;
            void operator=(const Mouse&) = delete;
            Mouse() = default;

        public:
            static Mouse& Instance();
            static void SomeServerFunc();

        public:
            static void SomeClientFunc();
        };
    }
}

//MessageHandler.h

#pragma once
#include "Keyboard.h"
#include "Mouse.h"
namespace wm
{
    template < class Keyboard, class Mouse >
    class _MessageHandler
    {
    public:
        static _MessageHandler& Instance();
        _MessageHandler(const _MessageHandler&) = delete;
        void operator=(const _MessageHandler&) = delete;

    private:
        _MessageHandler() = default;
        static void SomeMsgHandelingFunc(); //calls SomeServerFunc from window and mouse
    };

    typedef _MessageHandler<io::Keyboard, io::Mouse> MessageHandler;
}
```

As it is, above code compiles and runs fine. But I want to make the `SomeServerFunc` function in both keyboard and mouse classes private and make `MessageHandler` a friend of `Keyboard` and `Mouse`. I have tried different things but nothing has worked so far.

I was doing `friend class wm::MessageHandler;` but I got elaborated type refers to typedef error.
Then I found out after c++ 11,  you can do `friend wm::MessageHandler;` which gives loads of error. I also tried

`friend wm::_MessageHandler<io::Keyboard, io::Mouse>`;

`friend class wm::_MessageHandler<io::Keyboard, io::Mouse>`;

`friend wm::_MessageHandler<Keyboard, Mouse>`;

`friend class wm::_MessageHandler<Keyboard, Mouse>`;

No luck.

Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_MessageHandler`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: @PeteBecker Little too late this time but I will keep that in mind for my future projects :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to make the SomeServerFunc function in both keyboard and mouse classes private and make MessageHandler a friend of Keyboard and Mouse.

I add class declaration to mouse.h and keyboard.h,to make the compiler happy.Here is the code:

```
#pragma once

namespace wm
{
    template < class Keyboard, class Mouse >
    class _MessageHandler;
    namespace io
    {
        class Keyboard;
        class Mouse
        {
        friend class _MessageHandler<io::Keyboard, io::Mouse>;
        private:
            Mouse(const Mouse&) = delete;
            void operator=(const Mouse&) = delete;
            Mouse() = default;

        public:
            static Mouse& Instance();
        private:
            static void SomeServerFunc();

        public:
            static void SomeClientFunc();
        };
    }
}
```

```
#pragma once

namespace wm
{
    template < class Keyboard, class Mouse >
    class _MessageHandler;
    namespace io
    {
        class Mouse;
        class Keyboard
        {
        friend class _MessageHandler<io::Keyboard, io::Mouse>;
        private:
            Keyboard(const Keyboard&) = delete;
            void operator=(const Keyboard&) = delete; 
            Keyboard() = default;

        public:
            static Keyboard& Instance();
        private:
            static void SomeServerFunc();

        public:
            static void SomeClientFunc();
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `_MessageHandler` is not a class but a template. Try that:

```cpp
namespace wm
{
    template<class Keyboard, class Mouse> class MessageHandler;

    namespace io
    {
        class Keyboard
        {
            template<class Keyboard, class Mouse> friend class wm::MessageHandler;
            ...
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Says 'template' is not allowed with a little squiggly line under template.

Comment: Please find a correction.

Comment: Thanks. I think that was supposed to work but now It says namespace "wm" has no member "MessageHandler". I cannot include MessageHandler.h in Keyboard.h because It would be a circular reference. I think thats why it cant find MessageHandler

Comment: Try forward declaration then (see the update).